# Typescript callback arguments, which are resolved using a function

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I have a situation, where I call a function with some arguments, which are resolved using another function.

This is how the code looks.

```
function getArgs (): [string, number] {
  return ['hello world', 22]
}

function callFnWithArgs (callback) {
  callback(...getArgs())
}

callFnWithArgs(function (/* typehint here */) {
})
```

1. The function `callFnWithArgs` takes a callback and then execute it by passing some arguments.
2. Those arguments are given by another function called `getArgs()`.

So, is there any way to type hint, the arguments of the callback, which is the return value of another function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TypeScript 3.0 or newer, you can use the `ReturnType` type alias from the standard library to determine the return type of `getArgs` and then use a rest parameter to tie that to the callback of `callFnWithArgs`:

```
function getArgs (): [string, number] {
  return ['hello world', 22]
}

function callFnWithArgs (callback: (...args: ReturnType<typeof getArgs>) => void) {
  callback(...getArgs())
}

callFnWithArgs(function (a, b) {
  // a is string, b is number
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either define the type of `callback`:

```
function callFnWithArgs (callback: (a: string, b: number) => void) {
  callback(...getArgs())
}
```

Or if it's an option to pass the arguments from outside the function `callFnWithArgs`, you can use **Generic rest parameters**:

```
function getArgs (): [string, number] {
  return ['hello world', 22]
}

function callFnWithArgs<T extends any[]>(args: T, callback: (...args: T) => void) {
  callback(...args);
}

callFnWithArgs(getArgs(), (str, nr) => {
})
```

Yet another approach would be to create overloads with generic types for the parameters:

```
function getArgs(): [string, number] {
  return ['hello world', 22]
}
function callFnWithArgs<T>(callback: (a: T) => void);
function callFnWithArgs<T1, T2>(callback: (a: T1, b: T2) => void);
function callFnWithArgs(callback: (...args: any[]) => void) {
  callback(...getArgs());
}

callFnWithArgs<string, number>((str, nr) => {
})
```

Comment: I do like this approach, but if I have to call `getArgs()` when using `callFnWithArgs`, then it kills the purpose of the entire code.

Comment: Also there is an error 'A rest parameter must be of an array type.' in `(...args: T) => void`

Comment: @sherlock.92 You're probably not using TypeScript 3

Answer (score 0):

Does it solve your task?

```
function getArgs(): [string, number] {
  return ['hello world', 22]
}

function callFnWithArgs (callback: (a: string, b: number) => void) {
  const [a, b] = getArgs();
  callback(a, b);
}

callFnWithArgs(function (a: string, b: number) {
})
```

Comment: Nope! The `getArgs` function can be defined by the user of my code and they cannot change the signature of `callFnWithArgs`.